# R round to nearest .5 or .1

Tags: r, rounding, r-faq

I have a data set of stock prices that have already been rounded to 2 decimal places `(1234.56)`.  I am now trying to round to a specific value which is different for each stock.  Here are some examples:

```
Current Stock Price         Minimum Tick Increment       Desired Output
  123.45                            .50                      123.50
  155.03                            .10                      155.00
  138.24                            .50                      138.00
  129.94                            .10                      129.90
   ...                              ...                       ...
```

I'm not really sure how to do this but am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Probably,

```
round(a/b)*b
```

will do the work.

```
> a <- seq(.1,1,.13)
> b <- c(.1,.1,.1,.2,.3,.3,.7)
> data.frame(a, b, out = round(a/b)*b)
     a   b out
1 0.10 0.1 0.1
2 0.23 0.1 0.2
3 0.36 0.1 0.4
4 0.49 0.2 0.4
5 0.62 0.3 0.6
6 0.75 0.3 0.6
7 0.88 0.7 0.7
```

Comment: FWIW, `round_any` in the `plyr` package is a nice function implementing this very algorithm. It also takes an additional argument `f`, with choices `"round"`, `"ceiling"`, or `"floor"`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - You should make this a separate answer, as people often don't look in the comments

Comment: @Adam_G If you think it'd help others, do feel free to add such an answer. I'll check back to upvote it and start its march upwards towards greater visibility ;)

Answer (score 20):

I'm not familiar with R the language, but my method should work with any language with a ceiling function. I assume it's rounded UP to nearest 0.5:

```
a = ceiling(a*2) / 2

if a = 0.4, a = ceiling(0.4*2)/2 = ceiling(0.8)/2 = 1/2 = 0.5
if a = 0.9, a = ceiling(0.9*2)/2 = ceiling(1.8)/2 = 2/2 = 1
```

Comment: It is maybe better to write `a = ceiling(a / 0.5) * 0.5` since `a * 2` = `a / 0.5` and `x / 2` = `x * 0.5`

Comment: Also, you can replace `ceiling` with `floor` in this code to round down to the nearest 0.5.

Comment: `if a = 0.4, a = ...` Does former R versions allow comma. This does not work anymore.

Comment: This does not answer the question since it was required to round to the nearest value, sometimes up and sometimes down

Answer (score 17):

Like what JoshO'Brien said in the comments: `round_any` in the package `plyr` works very well!

```
> library(plyr)
> stocks <- c(123.45, 155.03, 138.24, 129.94)
> round_any(stocks,0.1)
[1] 123.4 155.0 138.2 129.9
> 
> round_any(stocks,0.5)
[1] 123.5 155.0 138.0 130.0
> 
> round_any(stocks,0.1,f = ceiling)
[1] 123.5 155.1 138.3 130.0
> 
> round_any(stocks,0.5,f = floor)
[1] 123.0 155.0 138.0 129.5
```

Read more here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/round_any

Answer (score 6):

The taRifx package has just such a function:

```
> library(taRifx)
> roundnear( seq(.1,1,.13), c(.1,.1,.1,.2,.3,.3,.7) )
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.7
```

In your case, just feed it the stock price and the minimum tick increment as its first and second arguments, and it should work its magic.

**N.B. This has now been deprecated.  See comment.**

Comment: should `0.36` for the ticks `0.1` be `0.4`?

Comment: I think rounding 0.36 to the nearest 0.1 increment should lead to 0.4.

Comment: Good point.  The algorithm used is embarrassingly convoluted compared to kohske's solution: frac = vec/roundvec; retvec = vec - (frac - floor(frac)) * roundvec .  Given that this functionality already exists in plyr, I'll likely deprecate roundnear and point people towards round_any.