# Round to a multiple and filter in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have very interesting problem, though I'd rather not to have one.
I have to round a number to a closes multiple so I followed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664976/r-round-to-nearest-5-or-1)
It used to work OK, until I've discover the bug with data.table

```
library(data.table)
options(digits = 20) # to see number representation
mround <- function (number, multiple) {
   return(multiple * round(number / multiple))
}
DT = data.table(a = mround(112.3, 0.1), b = "B")
DT[a == 112.3,] # works as expected, i.e returns one row
DT[a == 112.3 & b == 'B', ] # doesn't work
```

To be fair, with `data.frame` even the first filter doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: You problem is not clearly defined. You should add what you expect the output to be. Both lines return empty data.tables for me.

Comment: The first statement doesn't work for me in `data.table`, and it's unrelated to `data.table` or `data.frame`, but it's a problem of [floating point precision](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). See `DT[(a - 112.3)<1.e-6 & b == 'B',]` (using an error margin of 0.000001, if you want more precision see the link above or use `.Machine$double.eps^0.5` as does `all.equal`)

Comment: FWIW, round takes a `digits` parameter, `round(112.3,1)` should be enough and should avoid your actual problem)

Comment: @lmo I'd expect to see one row in this filter

Comment: @Tensibai round(112.3,1) is a solution, but not generic, as I need function to round to, say, 0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem of [floating point precision](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). 
See `DT[abs(a - 112.3)<1.e-6 & b == 'B',]` using an error margin of 0.000001 will give you proper result.

If you want more precision you can use `.Machine$double.eps^0.5` as does `all.equal`.

General advice is to never compare equality of floats but compare the difference with a value near enough to the machine precision to get around the precision drift between 0 and 1), more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847918/floating-point-precision-in-r)

One way to fix your problem could be to refactor your function to:

```
mround <- function (number, multiple, digits=nchar(strsplit(as.character(multiple),".",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2])) {

   round(multiple * round(number / multiple),digits)
}
```

I used a "convoluted" method to get the digits needed from the multiple passed as default significant digits, adapt to your needs (you may used 2 here for example, or force the precision when calling).
I removed the unnecessary `return` which just cause the interpreter to look for a function already called at end of the function call.

This way your output should be precise enough, but you'll still have corner cases:

```
> mround(112.37,0.2)
[1] 112.40000000000001
```

To use floats in joins, you can use (courtesy of David Arenburg):

```
setNumericRounding(1)
DT[.(112.3, 'B'), nomatch = 0L, on = .(a, b)]
```

Comment: I'd agree, but I want to use this column to in join. Can't imagine none use float for joining.

Comment: @kismsu I don't get what you mean... How is it a problem ? (sounds another question)

Comment: @kismsu I mean that `DT1[DT2,on=.((x.a-i.a < .Machine$double.eps^0.5)]` should do (untested)

Comment: I thought is you can't find the row with equal, then you wouldn't be able to see it in inner_join (merge)

Comment: You can't pass expressions to `on` argument yet IIRC. There should be a PR for this somewhere, if not, it should be definitely created.

Comment: @DavidArenburg let me recheck taht, I'm pretty sure to have play with somthing like this lately

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to @Tens great answer.

What seem to be happening are three things

- You have a floating point issue (as mentioned already)
- You are using and old data.table version
- Secondary indices are kicking in while you aren't aware of it

Using your setup

```
library(data.table)
options(digits = 20) # to see number representation

mround <- function (number, multiple) {
  return(multiple * round(number / multiple))
}

DT = data.table(a = mround(112.3, 0.1), b = "B")
```

So lets address the points above. Since you have a floating point and quoting `?setNumericRounding`

> Computers cannot represent some floating point numbers (such as 0.6) precisely, using base 2. This leads to unexpected behaviour when joining or grouping columns of type 'numeric'; i.e. 'double

This led `data.table` devs to implement the `setNumericRounding` which auto rounded floats so a the radix algorithm would behave as expected.

Prior to v1.9.8, `setNumericRounding(2)` was the default (hence your first example works), but after some complaints from users for inconsistency on GH (IIRC), since v1.9.8 the default was set back to `setNumericRounding(0)` in order to be consistent with `data.frame` behavior (see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#notes-2)). So if you'll update your data.table to the latest version, you will see that both `data.table` and `data.frame` will behave the same for your both examples (and both of your examples will fail).

Compare

```
setNumericRounding(0)
DT[a == 112.3]
## Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,b
```

To

```
setNumericRounding(1)
DT[a == 112.3]
#                     a b
# 1: 112.30000000000001 B
```

So you will ask, "*what on earth radix algorithm has to do with anything here*". So here we reach the third point above- ***secondary indices*** (please read [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html)). Lets see what actually happens when you are running you code above

```
options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)
DT[a == 112.3] # works as expected, i.e returns one row
# Creating new index 'a' <~~~~
# forder took 0 sec
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
#                     a b
# 1: 112.30000000000001 B
```

Lets checks the new secondary indices

```
indices(DT)
#[1] "a"
```

when you've ran `==`, data.table set `a` as your secondary index in order to perform future operations much more efficiently (this was introduced in v1.9.4, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-3)). In other words, you performed a binary join on `a` instead the usual vector scan like it was prior v1.9.4 (As a side note, this can be disabled by doing `options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)`, in that case, none of your examples will work even with `setNumericRounding(1)` unless you will explicitly specify a key using `setkey` or the `on` argument)

This is probably will also explain why

```
DT[a == 112.30000 & b == 'B']
```

doesn't work. You are sub-setting here by two columns and neither secondary indices or binary join don't (automatically) kick-in for an expressions such as `== & ==` (yet), hence you did a normal vector scan and `setNumericRounding(1)` didn't kick in

Though, you can set the keys manually and make it work, for instance (like I commented under @Tens answer), you can do

```
setNumericRounding(1) # make sure autoroundings turned on
DT[.(112.3, 'B'), nomatch = 0L, on = .(a, b)]
# Calculated ad hoc index in 0 secs
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
#        a b
# 1: 112.3 B
```

Or using the old way

```
setkey(DT, a, b)
DT[.(112.3, 'B'), nomatch = 0L]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
#        a b
# 1: 112.3 B
```

Comment: Thanks for summary. I actually haven't though about ad hoc index, forgot about this feature.