# X[Y] join of keyed data.table fails when key on numeric column AND data fread from a file

Tags: r, data.table

This one’s quite weird. Not sure if I’m missing something, or whether it’s a bug in `data.table` or `fread`.

I’m trying to “stretch” a data table with a time series where one time point is missing. When this table is read from a file, the X[Y] join fills NA’s in the missing row but **also** in other rows where data points are present. This happens **only** when the `t` column used for keying contains floats as opposed to integers.

```
library(data.table)

# This works fine; empty row at t=0.5
# is filled with NA after join

dt = data.table(id = as.integer(rep(0, 10)), 
                t = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 
                y = 1:10, 
                key = "id,t")
dt = dt[!(t == 0.5)]

dtAux = dt[, 
           .(seq(min(t), max(t), 0.1)),
           by = id]
setkey(dtAux, id, V1)

dt[dtAux]

    id   t  y
 1:  0 0.1  1
 2:  0 0.2  2
 3:  0 0.3  3
 4:  0 0.4  4
 5:  0 0.5 NA
 6:  0 0.6  6
 7:  0 0.7  7
 8:  0 0.8  8
 9:  0 0.9  9
10:  0 1.0 10

# This fails; NA’s created in multiple rows

fwrite(dt, "test.csv", row.names = F)
dtFromFile = fread("test.csv")
setkey(dtFromFile, id, t)

dtAux = dtFromFile[, 
                   .(seq(min(t), max(t), 0.1)),
                   by = id]
setkey(dtAux, id, V1)

dtFromFile[dtAux]

    id   t  y
 1:  0 0.1  1
 2:  0 0.2  2
 3:  0 0.3 NA
 4:  0 0.4  4
 5:  0 0.5 NA
 6:  0 0.6  6
 7:  0 0.7 NA
 8:  0 0.8  8
 9:  0 0.9  9
10:  0 1.0 10
```

Tested on 3.6.1 with `data.table` 1.12.4

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Comment: It's a precision problem. See `dt$t-dtFromFile$t`. You'll see that the values read from file aren't exactly the same as the original

Comment: @Rohit I was fooled by `all.equal` that yielded `TRUE`. Then, of course, when I reduce `tolerance` parameter to something like `1e-18` I get the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?setNumericRounding`

> Computers cannot represent some floating point numbers (such as 0.6) precisely, using base 2. This
>   leads to unexpected behaviour when joining or grouping columns of type ’numeric’; i.e. ’double’,
>   see example below. In cases where this is undesirable, data.table allows rounding such data up to
>   approximately 11 s.f. which is plenty of digits for many cases. This is achieved by rounding the
>   last 2 bytes off the significand. Other possible values are 1 byte rounding, or no rounding (full
>   precision, default).
>   It is bytes rather than bits because it is tied in with the radix sort algorithm for sorting numerics
>   which sorts byte by byte. With the default rounding of 0 bytes, at most 8 passes are needed. With
>   rounding of 2 bytes, at most 6 passes are needed (and therefore might be a tad faster).
>   For large numbers (integers > 2^31), we recommend using bit64::integer64, even though the
>   default is to round off 0 bytes (full precision).

To fix it you can use the below before running your code.

```
setNumericRounding(2)
```

See `?setNumericRounding` for more examples and also [Round to a multiple and filter in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223847/round-to-a-multiple-and-filter-in-data-table/41225211#41225211)

---

edit: OP is asking why it works when its in the script but not when data is read from the file. It might be due to ALTREP (see slide 9 [here](https://www.r-project.org/dsc/2017/slides/dsc2017.pdf)).

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.12.2 R Win x64
dt_seq <- data.table(x = seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.2), v=1:3, key = "x")
dt_c <- data.table(x = c(0.1,0.3,0.5), v=1:3, key = "x")

dtAux_seq = data.table(x=seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.1), key="x")
dtAux_c = data.table(x=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), key="x")

fwrite(dt_seq, "test.csv")
dtFromFile <- fread("test.csv", key="x")
```

Testing diff joins:

```
> dt_seq[dtAux_seq]
     x  v
1: 0.1  1
2: 0.2 NA
3: 0.3  2
4: 0.4 NA
5: 0.5  3

> dt_c[dtAux_seq]
     x  v
1: 0.1  1
2: 0.2 NA
3: 0.3 NA
4: 0.4 NA
5: 0.5  3

> dtFromFile[dtAux_seq]
     x  v
1: 0.1  1
2: 0.2 NA
3: 0.3 NA
4: 0.4 NA
5: 0.5  3
```

Explicitly typing values in `dtAux_c`:

```
> dt_seq[dtAux_c]
     x  v
1: 0.1  1
2: 0.2 NA
3: 0.3 NA
4: 0.4 NA
5: 0.5  3

> dt_c[dtAux_c]
     x  v
1: 0.1  1
2: 0.2 NA
3: 0.3  2
4: 0.4 NA
5: 0.5  3

> dtFromFile[dtAux_c]
     x  v
1: 0.1  1
2: 0.2 NA
3: 0.3  2
4: 0.4 NA
5: 0.5  3
```

Comment: Makes sense. Though, I’m still wondering why things work fine when dt is defined explicitly in the script.

Comment: i suspect it has something to do with ALTREP but i cannot confirm.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to floating point errors on decimal values. This is not a R-specific issue, but just the way computers handle decimals.
read for more info: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558)

When joining on decimal values, a solution is to round them first to the relevant number of digits.

```
dtAux2 = dtFromFile[, 
                   .( round( seq(min(t), max(t), 0.1), digits = 1 ) ),
                   by = id]
dt_Aux2
setkey(dtAux2, id, V1)

dtFromFile[dtAux2]

#   id   t  y
#1:  0 0.1  1
#2:  0 0.2  2
#3:  0 0.3  3
#4:  0 0.4  4
#5:  0 0.5 NA
#6:  0 0.6  6
#7:  0 0.7  7
#8:  0 0.8  8
#9:  0 0.9  9
#10:  0 1.0 10
```