# round to specific value r

Tags: r, rounding

I have a list of co-ordinates that I need to round at 0.1 intervals

Easy enough with `mutate(Long=round(Long/0.1)*0.1` (not sure if that's most efficient but it works and isn't the issue today.

The issue is I need to round to match the following (all Longs end in 0.04, Lats in 0.03)

For example Lat 53.15 would typically round UP to 53.2 but I need it to round down to 53.13

```
   Long   Lat 
1 -3.24 53.13 
2 -3.14 53.13 
3 -3.04 53.13 
4 -2.94 53.13 
5 -2.84 53.13 
6 -2.74 53.13
```

Comment: I would shift your `Longs` data down by subtracting 0.04, then round it to the nearest 0.1, and then undo the shift by adding 0.04. (And similarly for `Lats`.)

Comment: What would a `Lat` of 50.00 round to, 50.03 or 49.93? Could you expand your examples a bit and add your desired output of those examples? The data provided doesnt help much since they are already in the desired format. Good luck!

Comment: You want to *"round at 0.1 intervals"*, but then you say "end in 0.04" or 0.03. It sounds like your first sentence is for a different problem and not what you're asking about today. Please edit and either remove the first two sentences or edit and add explanations on how "0.1 intervals" and "0.03/0.04" are supposed to be compatible.

Comment: What about `53.39` and `53.99`, what should they round to? Should negatives round "up/down irrespective of sign", or should they round closer/further from zero? Finally, if you have coordinates, why are you changing the value at the 1/100ths level?

Comment: My interpretation is that each number needs to be rounded to nearest value from the set `{..., 0.04, 0.14, 0.24, ... }`, though as I'm typing this I realize that there's a bit of an irregularity at the switch from positive to negative values, so I'll need adjust my answer.

Comment: With new edits, my answer rounds to the nearest number from the set `{..., -0.24, -0.14, -0.04, 0.4, 0.14, 0.24, ...}`,  with the exception of exactly `0` which stays `0` as it is equidistant from -0.04 and 0.04.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. In this example all Longs are negative and all Lats positive.

I was thinking along the lines of extracting the decimal values somehow and having an if statement along the lines of (for Lat) if decimals < 0.53 round down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift your data so that you can round it to a convenient value, then unshift it. (With credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665247/903061) for the round logic without the offset.)

```
round_offset = function(x, precision, offset) {
  round((x - offset * sign(x)) / precision) * precision + offset * sign(x)
}
```

Demonstration below - we can see that all the `rounded` values end in 0.04, and the difference from the original values are all less than 0.05, so it appears to be working correctly.

```
set.seed(47)
xx = seq(-0.3, 0.8, by = 0.1) 
xx = xx + runif(length(xx), min = -.05, max = .05)

result = cbind(xx, rounded = round_offset(xx, precision = 0.1, offset = 0.04))
cbind(result, diff = result[, 2] - result[, 1])
#                xx rounded         diff
#  [1,] -0.25230380   -0.24  0.012303800
#  [2,] -0.21260840   -0.24 -0.027391605
#  [3,] -0.07384980   -0.04  0.033849797
#  [4,]  0.03224916    0.04  0.007750839
#  [5,]  0.10735444    0.14  0.032645558
#  [6,]  0.21914124    0.24  0.020858757
#  [7,]  0.28890619    0.24 -0.048906185
#  [8,]  0.39689460    0.44  0.043105403
#  [9,]  0.50433097    0.54  0.035669026
# [10,]  0.64248920    0.64 -0.002489205
# [11,]  0.66387976    0.64 -0.023879758
# [12,]  0.82019872    0.84  0.019801280
```

Note that 0 will not be rounded as it's equidistant from both -0.04 and 0.04. If you want 0 to be rounded, I'd handle it as an exception after applying this algorithm. (Or perhaps by nudging the input just a little bit, if you add `1e-8` to your input `0` will be rounded up and nothing else is likely to be affected.)